# Clickable textView does not work

Tags: java, android, textview

I have `TextView` but it doesn't work when I click it.

```
My java source code:

 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public TextView tv1;
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Relative layout oluşturduk
        final RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        //Buttonumuzu oluşturduk
        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNotEkle);
        //Alert dialog oluşturdul
        final AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        //Edit Text oluşturduk
        final EditText dersAdiGir = new  EditText(MainActivity.this);
        final EditText dersSaatiGir = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        tv1 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        dersAdiGir.setHint("Ders Adi Giriniz");
        dersSaatiGir.setHint("Ders Saati Giriniz");
        dersSaatiGir.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        LinearLayout etLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
        etLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        etLayout.addView(dersAdiGir);
        etLayout.addView(dersSaatiGir);
        build.setView(etLayout);
        //Linear layout oluşturduk bu sayede alt alta ders adlarını sıralayacağız
        final LinearLayout layoutDers = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDers);

        //Alert dialoga button ekledik
        build.setPositiveButton("Tamam", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Butttona tıkladığında olacaklar

                tv1.setClickable(true);
                String girilenDers = dersAdiGir.getText().toString();//EditText içinden girilen Text'i alacağız.
                int girilenDersSaati = Integer.parseInt(dersSaatiGir.getText().toString());;
                tv1.setText(girilenDers);//
                layoutDers.addView(tv1);//Linearlayout'a dersi ekledik
                dialog.dismiss();//Dialogdan çıktık.

            }
        });

        //Yeni bir dialog oluşturduk. ve buttona tıklandığında dialog penceresi gösterilecek.
        final AlertDialog alertDersAdi = build.create();
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                alertDersAdi.show();
            }
        });
        tv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotEkle.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

}
}
```

When I click on the `TextView` it doesn't trigger the `Intent` :( What's wrong? Please help me. Thanks to all.

Comment: Do you added `tv1` on first time - when you create it? Or only in click method from positive button?

Comment: It'll be helpful if you show us the xml file code.

Comment: Onclick of the positive button you are displaying the text view, so write the click listener after enabling the text view itself

Comment: @Konrad Krakowiak sorry my friend i dont understand :( my english is not good :( i first  create tv1 = new TextView(MainActivity.this); after dialog buildier. My friend, my request is i want a create textView when i click on alert button and  i want click that textview after creating.

Comment: Ok I see, So the best way will be using xml - read about layouts on android because you choose wrong way to implement your functionality

Comment: please provide a screenshot your explanation is not a very good one..

Comment: Edited. I copy full javacode to topic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "find" the TextView.

```
tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id./*id of your textview*/);
```

To set the id, add this to your textView in your xml:

```
android:id="@+id/textView"
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a TextView clickable add the following line to your TextView in **xml** file:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

Or in your **Java** Class:

```
textView.setClickable(true);
```

after that you can set onClickListener to it:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent inte = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotEkle.class);
            startActivity(inte);
        }
    });
```

**EDIT:** So in your case:

Xml if you have one:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        .... />
```

and if programmatically, add in Java class:

```
// For example If you're using a LinearLayout
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylayoutID)
TextView txt1 = new TextView(MyClass.this);
txt1.setText("hallo hallo");
txt1.setClickable(true);
linearLayout.addView(txt1);
```

Then setOnClickListener

```
txt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent inte = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotEkle.class);
                startActivity(inte);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding text view to your layout at this line

```
layoutDers.addView(tv1);
```

So for click listener to work, you must only add click listener to the view only after it is added to the layout. So add the click listener after the above line.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not very clean... But here is what you should do:

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    final TextView tv1 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
    tv1.setClickable(true);
    //Butttona tıkladığında olacaklar
    String girilenDers = dersAdiGir.getText().toString(); //EditText içinden girilen Text'i alacağız.
    int girilenDersSaati =  Integer.parseInt(dersSaatiGir.getText().toString());
    tv1.setText(girilenDers);//                
    layoutDers.addView(tv1);//Linearlayout'a dersi ekledik

    tv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent inte = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NotEkle.class);
            startActivity(inte);

        }
    });

    // Set the View here...
    build.setView(layoutDers);
    build.setPositiveButton("Tamam", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();//Dialogdan çıktık.
        }
    });
   final AlertDialog alertDersAdi = build.create();
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alertDersAdi.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: but i need create textview with positive button.